# How to compare BSTR against a string in c/c++?

Tags: c++, windows, com, activex

```
wprintf(L"Selecting Audio Input Device: %s\n", 
                            varName.bstrVal);

if(0 == strcmp(varName.bstrVal, "IP Camera [JPEG/MJPEG]"))...
```

The above reports :

```
error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BSTR' to 'const char *'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use `wcscmp` instead:

```
if(0 == wcscmp(varName.bstrVal, L"IP Camera [JPEG/MJPEG]"))
{
}
```

Here is a [description of the BSTR data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx), it has a length prefix and a real string part which is just an array of WCHAR characters.  It also has 2 NULL terminators.

The only thing to look out for is that the BSTR data type can contain embedded NULLs in the string portion, so `wcscmp` will only work in the cases where the BSTR does not contain embedded NULLs (which is probably most cases).

Comment: Why some functions are prefixed with `w` while some are `wc`?

Comment: @COMer: I'm not sure but wcs stands for wide character string.

Comment: @COMer: I'm guessing "str" gets replaced with "wcs" (e.g. strcmp -> wcscmp, strdup -> wcsdup), but functions without "str" get a "w" inserted somewhere (e.g. printf -> wprintf, fopen -> _wfopen).

Answer (score 1):

As a richer alternative to the C runtime, you could use the Unicode CompareString or [CompareStringEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317761(v=VS.85).aspx/) APIs in Win32.  If you don't have charset issues to consider, wcscmp is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
static const std::wstring IPCamera = L"IP Camera [JPEG/MJPEG]";
if (varName.bstrVal == IPCamera {
  //...
```

Comment: Trying that failed for me.  The example is missing a right parenthesis, which I corrected (it compiled), but the logic does not see two identical strings as equal.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers here are either outright wrong or partially incorrect because they are ignoring the fact that both `BSTR` and `std::wstring` can contain multiple embedded null characters.

That means they should not be compared using `wcscmp()`, which will stop comparison on the first `\0` it encounters in either string.

Here is how to properly compare `BSTR` with `std::wstring`:

```
// Windows.h defines min() and max() as macros
#define NOMINMAX

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

// std::string_literals namespace requires C++14,
// but it is needed only to construct strings with
// embedded nulls, not for the comparison itself
using namespace std::string_literals;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    std::wstring    String1 = L"I am a happy BSTR \0with \0embedded \0null chars"s;
    std::wstring    Temp = L"I am a happy bstr \0with \0embedded \0NULL chars"s;
    BSTR            String2 = SysAllocStringLen(Temp.c_str(), Temp.size());

    if (String2 == nullptr) {
        return ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }

    // make sure not to create a security vulnerability by
    // reading past the end of either buffer when comparing
    const size_t MaxCount = std::min(String1.size(), static_cast<size_t>(SysStringLen(String2)));

    bool Equal = wcsncmp(String1.c_str(), String2, MaxCount) == 0;

    if (Equal) {
        wprintf(L"Strings are equal\n");
    } else {
        wprintf(L"Strings are NOT equal\n");
    }

    SysFreeString(String2);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the example will print "Strings are NOT equal" unless you change it to use `_wcsnicmp()` for case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score -1):

I always construct `_bstr_t` wrappers around BSTRs. It makes things quite a bit easier and more idiomatic:

```
if(std::string("IP Camera [JPEG/MJPEG]") ==
                   static_cast<const char*>( _bstr_t(varName.bstrVal) )
{
}
```

Comment: Not such a great idea: the _bstr_t constructor makes a full-length copy of the string in varName.bstrVal.

Comment: This also does a run-time conversion of the bstr from unicode to ANSI, which is unnecessary since you could just compare against a unicode literal in the first place.