# if condition with _bstr_t variable

Tags: visual-c++, types

I need to compare a known "string" value with "_bstr_t" variable.  I have converted "_bstr_t" into "string". but why the below did not work. thanks

```
   _bstr_t bstr = L"My string"; 

   if (_bstr_t(bstr,false)=="My string")
   {
     int pp=0;
   }
```

Comment: What is `bstr` here?

Comment: sorry, here is "bstr" definition. _bstr_t bstr = L"My string";

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700772/how-to-compare-bstr-against-a-string-in-c-c

Comment: If the variable `bstr` is already type `_bstr_t` why are you constructing another `_bstr_t` in the `if` expression?

Comment: variable 'bstr' is type '_bstr_t', if I write  "if (bstr=="My string")". there is an error to compare "_bstr_t" and "string". I was trying to convert "bstr" into "string" type by using "_bstr_t(bstr,false)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was trying to convert "bstr" into "string" type by using "_bstr_t(bstr,false)"

What `_bstr_t(bstr,false)` does is to create a second `_bstr_t` which points to the same `BSTR` that `bstr` points to.

> if I write "if (bstr=="My string")". there is an error …

The compiler is going to have a hard time figuring out what `==` means in this case because the left side of the `==` is a `_bstr_t` and the right side is a `const char [10]`

It could be interpreted as the built-in pointer equality operator that is used to compare two pointers - to see if they both point to the same location.  **Or** it could mean the [`_bstr_t` operator `==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-relational-operators?view=vs-2017) which compares two `_bstr_t` to see if they are equal lexicographically.

> I need to compare a known "string" value with "_bstr_t" variable

Since you want a lexicographical comparison, you probably want the `_bstr_t operator ==`.  One way to do that would be to construct a `_bstr_t` from your string constant.

```
if (bstr == _bstr_t("My string"))
{
    int pp = 0;
}
```