# Using ternary operator in c++ returns false condition always

Tags: c++

I am using a statement with ternary operator which is always returning the other value.

```
BSTR pVal = L"Yes";

bool val = pVal == L"Yes" ? true : false;
```

this statement returns

```
 val = false;
```

I expect it to return true here. Am i making it wrong?

Comment: `BSTR` types cannot be compared directly using `==`.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but this is not a valid way to create a `BSTR`. They're supposed to be allocated with `SysAllocString`. In C++ it's best to use a wrapper type like `_bstr_t`, which will also solve your comparison issues.

Comment: [How to compare BSTR against a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700772/how-to-compare-bstr-against-a-string-in-c-c)

Comment: Not a bug, but `a == b ? true : false` is usually written `a == b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot here is wrong.

`==` on `BSTR` compares pointer values.  Two `L"Yes"` being pointer-equal is implementation defined.

`bool_expr?true:false` is a noop.

```
bool val = wcscmp(pVal, L"Yes") == 0;
```

is probably what you want.

```
BSTR pVal = L"Yes";
```

is bad news; that isn't how you are supposed to create a BSTR.  BSTR are supposed to be pascal-esque strings allocated in a specific region of memory.

```
BSTR pVal = SysAllocString(L"Yes");
```

is usually better.

Using `wcscmp` is valid on a `BSTR`, as `BSTR` is guaranteed null terminated.  But assigning a null terminated string to a `BSTR` is not a good plan; the code consuming the `BSTR` may expect the length field to come before the first character.

It may even be a good plan to use `_bstr_t` which is a C++ wrapper around `BSTR`.

It is also usually a good idea to compare `BSTR` to `BSTR` and not using C APIs; a `BSTR` can contain embedded NULs, and C APIs stop at the first NUL.

```
_bstr_t pVal = L"Yes";

bool val = pVal == _bstr_t(L"Yes");
```

`_bstr_t` has an `operator==` that does a reasonable thing.

Comment: `bstr_t` is a completely diferent type than _wide string_, one need to use the (Windows) OS conversion functions to convert one into another.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not completely different (you can use wcscmp), but yes, I added that.

Comment: You cannot safely use the C string functions. BSTRs can contain embedded NUL characters. They are Pascal-style strings, with the length stored inside the string. Not C-style strings with sentinel terminator characters.

Comment: @CodyGray Part of that depends on what you want `==` to do, but yes, probably wrapping the other `L"Yes"` in a BSTR and using BSTR-approved comparisons is a good plan.  On the other hand, I can guarantee I can find an issue with every single `==` on two strings; there are languages where multiple characters become fewer in other cases, combinations of characters codes that can be treated identically or not with other characters, etc.

Comment: Yeah, just to be clear, it wasn't a criticism of your answer so much as a response to your discussion with πάντα in the comments. In this very limited case, where you're comparing to a string literal, it would obviously be fine to use `wcscmp`. I just wanted to explain why it's not a valid approach *in general*.

Comment: @cody yet, if the bstr contains `"Yes\0No"` it gives a false positive.  Depending on how you define == that is.